# Using OpenGL Shader on a QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl, qgraphicsview

I am trying to use an OpenGL Shader on a QGrapicsView.
My graphic card is a NVidia GeForce GT 425M. I made my experiments on a Ubuntu 12.04 with the NVidia driver 295.40.

I Create a QMainWindow containing two QGraphicsView, each graphics view are displaying the same scene. On One of the Graphics View, I setup an OpenGL View port.
The OpenGL View Port is a QGLWidget I had overloaded with the loading of the vertex and fragment shader programs.

Look at my QMainWindow constructor :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->gvShaded->setScene(m_scene);
    ui->gvUnshaded->setScene(m_scene);
    m_glWidget = new QGLScene();
    ui->gvShaded->setViewport(m_glWidget);
    m_glWidget->updateGL();
    if(m_glWidget->context()->isValid())
    {
        qDebug()<<"GL Context is valid";
    }else
    {
        qWarning()<<"GL Context is not valid";
    }

    qDebug() << "Opengl Version : " << m_glWidget->context()->format().openGLVersionFlags();

    QBrush brush(QLinearGradient(0,0,20,0));
    brush.setColor(Qt::blue);
    QGraphicsRectItem* rect = m_scene->addRect(0,0,20,20,QPen(Qt::black), brush);

    ui->gvShaded->ensureVisible(rect);
    ui->gvUnshaded->ensureVisible(rect);
}
```

As you can see I instantiate the object QGLScene which is :

```
class QGLScene : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    QGLScene(QWidget* _parent=0);
protected :
    virtual void initializeGL();
};
```

My GLWidget Construction is :

```
QGLScene::QGLScene(QWidget *_parent)
    :QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DepthBuffer), _parent)
{
}
```

And definition of initializeGL is :

```
void QGLScene::initializeGL()
{
    qDebug() << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    QGLShader fragmentShader(QGLShader::Fragment, context(), this);
    QGLShader vertexShader(QGLShader::Vertex, context(), this);
    QGLShaderProgram pgm(context(), this);
    if(vertexShader.compileSourceFile("./vertexShader.glsl"))
    {
        if(fragmentShader.compileSourceFile("./fragmentShader.glsl"))
        {
            pgm.addShader(&fragmentShader);
            pgm.addShader(&vertexShader);
            pgm.link();
            pgm.bind();
            qDebug() << "Shader bien chargé : "<< pgm.log();
        }else
        {
            qDebug() << "Problem when loading fragment shader :";
            qDebug() << fragmentShader.log();
            qDebug() << QString(fragmentShader.sourceCode());
        }
    }else
    {
        qDebug() << "Problem when loading vertex shader :";
        qDebug() << vertexShader.log();
        qDebug() << QString(vertexShader.sourceCode());
    }
}
```

My shaders are very useless shaders : 
Vertex :

```
 #version 150

uniform mat4 viewMatrix, projMatrix;

in vec4 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * position ;
}
```

Fragment :

```
#version 150

in vec3 Color;
out vec4 outputF;

void main()
{
    outputF = vec4(1.0, 0, 0, 1.);
}
```

So I attempt to have my Shaded Graphics view as a big red square because I think I enforced the pixels to be red (in my fragment shader).

I have no shader compilation error, but my two scene are the same.
Of course, the program pass into the initializeGL function (I can read the **PRETTY_FUNCTION**).

Does some one have an explanation ?

Comment: Do you check for linker errors as well as compile errors? You can get them at both stages, but I don't see any checking of the pgm.link() operation.

Comment: I made a test on both  pgm.link(); and  pgm.bind(); and the two lines return true, so there is no linking problem...

Comment: Your shaders are objects instantiated on the stack. Their reference are lost past initializeGL(). And I don't see any PRETTY_FUNCTION  ("Shader bien chargé" ?). This code should segfault.